# Reverse proxy apache not working

Tags: apache2, mod-proxy

I have my subdomain pointing to my server IP.

I have enabled

```
sudo a2enmod proxy 
sudo a2enmod proxy_http 
sudo a2enmod proxy_wstunnel
```

Here is my `virtualhost.conf` file contents:

```
ProxyRequests off

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /socket.io/1/websocket ws:/myserverip:4567/socket.io/1/websocket
ProxyPassReverse /socket.io/1/websocket ws://myserverip:4567/socket.io/1/websocket

ProxyPass /socket.io/ http://myserverip:4567/socket.io/
ProxyPassReverse /socket.io/ http://myserverip:4567/socket.io/

ProxyPass / http://myserverip:4567/
ProxyPassReverse / http://myserverip:4567/
```

Comment: In what way is it not working, what is happening, what errors are you getting, providing more information would be good.